# Why does the entanglement of quantum fields depend on their distance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-entanglement

When watching [Seans Carrol's "*A Brief History of Quantum Mechanics*"](https://youtu.be/5hVmeOCJjOU?t=3011), he mentioned around the 50th minute (the video I linked to starts at that point) that

> [about quantum fields in vacuum] ... and guess what! The closer they are to each other, the more entangled they are.

**Why is it so? I was under the impression that entanglement is not dependent on the distance** (two entangled particles getting further from each other are not less entangled).

---

If this is at all possible I would be grateful for an answer understandable by an arts major - just kidding a bit, I simply would like to avoid an answer which starts with

[image]

<sup>courtesy of [Redorbit](https://www.redorbit.com/news/technology/1113303067/quantum-physics-is-less-complicated-than-we-thought-121914/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that Carrol is referring to [cluster decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_decomposition_theorem), a principle satisfied by many quantum field theories.  This principle says that if two quantities are located in spacelike-separated regions very far from one another, then they are going to be uncorrelated.  That is, if operators $A$ and $B$ are localized in two spacelike-separated regions a distance $\ell$ apart, we have $\langle A B \rangle \to \langle A \rangle\langle B \rangle$ as $\ell \to \infty$.  We can usually give a more detailed statement of how quickly the correlation dies off.  For example, in a theory of a field with mass $m$ the bound on the difference $\lvert\langle A B \rangle - \langle A \rangle\langle B \rangle\rvert$ goes like $e^{-m\ell}$, and in a massless theory the difference goes to zero faster than $\ell^{-N}$ for any $N$.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should pay any attention to this. Entanglement refers to quantum states, not to quantum fields.